# Múltiplas chaves estrangeiras vindo da mesma tabela. É possível?

Tags: mysql

Estou estudando MySql usando o MySql Workbrench para criar um diagrama da minha base de dados e surgiu a seguinte situação:
Imagine que tenho a tabela_A e a tabela_intensidade, onde :

**Estrutura da tabela_A:**
id, nome, intensidade_1, intensidade_2

**Estrutura da tabela_intensidade:** id_intensidade, descricao_intensidade

**A minha dúvida é:** Gostaria que os campos intensidade_1 e intensidade_2 da tabela_A recebessem a id_intensidade da tabela intensidade, em uma relação de cardinalidade de 1 pra 1. Ou seja, criar duas chaves estrangeiras da mesma tabela. Isso é possível? Seria essa a maneira correta?

Vou tentar criar um cenário mais 'real'.

Imagine um cenário no ramo da oceanografia, onde a tabela_A , além da chave primaria, precise guardar também a direção do vento(dir_vento) e a direção da ondulação(dir_ondulacao). Sabendo que a tabela_ventos(id_vento, desc_vento) possui todas as direções possíveis, e ambos os campos dir_vento e dir_ondulacao também são ventos, seria possível que eles guardassem a id_vento, para futuramente eu resgatar a dsc_vento da tabela vento a partir deles?? ou seja, seriam os campos dir_vento e dir_ondulacao chaves estrangeiras da tabela_ventos?

Intenderam mais ou menos a ideia?

Comment: Não seria melhor descrever um pouco onde quer chegar com isso?

Comment: não tem nada de errado o jeito que você esta fazendo, só porque é um caso diferente as pessoas acham que ta errado, já postei a resposta só rodar o script ai.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só rodar o script e ver se é isso mesmo.

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`tabela_intensidade` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descricao_intensidade` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

  CREATE TABLE `test`.`tabela_a` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `intensidade1` INT NULL,
  `intensidade2` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

  ALTER TABLE `test`.`tabela_a` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk01`
  FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
  REFERENCES `test`.`tabela_intensidade` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk02`
  FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
  REFERENCES `test`.`tabela_intensidade` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

INSERT INTO `test`.`tabela_intensidade` (`id`, `descricao_intensidade`) VALUES ('1', 'dir_vento - sul');
INSERT INTO `test`.`tabela_intensidade` (`id`, `descricao_intensidade`) VALUES ('2', 'dir_ondulacao - norte');
INSERT INTO `test`.`tabela_intensidade` (`descricao_intensidade`) VALUES ('dir_vento - leste');
INSERT INTO `test`.`tabela_intensidade` (`descricao_intensidade`) VALUES ('dir_ondulaco - oeste');

INSERT INTO `test`.`tabela_a` (`nome`, `intensidade1`, `intensidade2`) VALUES ('registro01', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `test`.`tabela_a` (`nome`, `intensidade1`, `intensidade2`) VALUES ('registro02', '3', '4');

SELECT 
a.*,
(select descricao_intensidade from tabela_intensidade b where a.intensidade1=b.id) as intensidade,
(select descricao_intensidade from tabela_intensidade b where a.intensidade2=b.id) as intensidade
FROM test.tabela_a a;
```

Comment: Valeu Maison. Pelo visto acho que estou indo no caminho certo. Acabei levando meu raciocínio por este caminho na tentativa de 'economizar' tabelas, já que dir_vento é vento  e dir_ondulacao também é vento, e como preciso guardar cada um em uma linha da tabela, mas com valores diferentes, achei que criar uma segunda tabela (tabela_intensidade) para guardar as direções, e usa-la posteriormente em um relacionamento seria o correto. Mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: Maison, ultima pergunta. Como seria uma consulta para mostrar todos os registros da tabela_A, trazendo o campo descricao_intensidade da tabela_intensidade, referente a dir_vento e dir_ondulacao?

Comment: @sThiago essa última pergunta já esta ai no script, é o SELECT com sub-query relacionando as chaves FK da tabela_A com a PK da tabela_intensidade

Comment: Exatamente isso brother. Valew !

Answer (score 3):

Não há problema algum em criar mais de uma chave estrangeira para a mesma tabela. Por quê? Porque relacionamentos entre as tabelas possuem **semântica** e isso pode exigir uma ligação diferente para a mesma tabela

As tabelas podem, inclusive, possuirem chave estrangeira para ela mesma.

Se é a maneira correta para o seu caso, é preciso saber mais sobre o caso: 
Serão sempre apenas 2? Não vale fazer uma cardinalidade 1 para muitos? 
Ou isso iria complicar demais o código do negócio sem necessidade?

Enfim, há sim a possibilidade de fazer. Mas a corretude da solução vai depender de mais informações

Comment: Olá Felipe, editei minha pergunta na tentativa de elabora-la melhor. Poderia dar uma olhada e ver se entende onde quero chegar? Obrigado.

Comment: @sThiago Não entendi. Vc perguntou se era possível, eu respondi que era. Quanto a maneira "correta", isso é muito variável e amplo. Eu diria que essa é UMA maneira correta. O que vc esperava de resposta?

Comment: Sua resposta ajudou muito. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Não seria a maneira correta.

Na Tabela_A tenha apenas um campo chamado *id_intensidade*.

E a cada inserção seria um novo registro com a chave estrangeira. Muito mais fácil controlar via programação depois.

E isso seria um relacionamento com cardinalidade 1 para 1 ou 1 para muitos.